# What is faster: include() or file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, include, file-get-contents

I am working on a SEO system for my project and am optimizing all links with a single page.

Excerpt from `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ seo.php [L,QSA]
```

This SEO file (`seo.php`) will get the requested path and parse it to be as valid url into my script.

I am using `include('cat.php?catid=1')` at the end of `seo.php` and everything is working fine, but I wonder which is faster: `include()` or `file_get_contents()`?

When I use `file_get_content('cat.php?catid=1')`, it displays the source of the PHP file, but when I use `file_get_content('http://localhost/cat.php?catid=1')`, it displays the normal page.

So, which is faster: `file_get_content()` or `include()`?

Comment: `include('cat.php?catid=1')` shouldn't work at all, since PHP will see that as a local file-system operation and NOT use an http request. Do you actually have a local file name `cat.php?catid=1`? Local file system options do NOT use query strings.

Comment: Seems `include` works faster for some 8 milliseconds. But I tested only 3 times (opened page)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are of course different

- Include will parse PHP code inside it
- file_get_contents will return just the content

So if yuo want just to retrive the html content of page use `file_get_contents` otherwise if you need to parse PHP code use `include();`

Notice: if you want to retrive the content of a page hosted on your website you should use local path not web path to your resource, ie:

- Do: `file_get_contents('/home/user/site/file.html');`
- Do Not: `file_get_contents('http://example.com/file.html');`

Comment: You can also `include()` a HTML template instead of `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: thank you for your advice :) its helped me but u said include well parse the php code inside it u mean its well parse the php cods inside cat.php twice ? and where is the problem if i use file_get_content('http://localhost/cat.php?catid=1')

Answer (score 2):

If you're loading your own local files as part of the template, use either `require`, or `include`. Of course you could use `require_once` or `include_once`, but don't use `file_get_contents` for local files.

This doesn't have anything to do with performance, it's about purpose. `file_get_contents` doesn't exist for dynamically loading in template dependencies. Not unless you need to parse their content prior to showing, or they're on some other domain, which would be very unlikely.

Comment: When using SVG and run into problems I think it can be a solution to run it with file_get_contents. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908855/wordpress-include-svg-file-error

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a pointless question. Both of them fast enough. No need to bug yourself with questions out of nowhere.
2. include('cat.php?catid=1'); will never work
3. calling your own code via HTTP request is wrong.

So, the code should be

```
include('cat.php');
```

Comment: yes this is what i did , i am sorry i am setting $_GET method before i call cat.php

Comment: so, keep it. why asking a question at all?

Comment: for knowledge my friend :) i don't have high experience like u and i am afraid to miss with something , so thank you very much u make me relax now because my work is fine

Comment: For the knowledge one have to ask what's the essential difference between these 2... and eventually attend to manual. While asking which is faster makes no point nor knowledge.

Answer (score -5):

Correction: you cant use local path with `file_get_contents`:

```
file_get_contents('/home/user/site/file.html');  <-- will never work.

file_get_contents('http://site.com/file.html');  <-- this should work.
```

Comment: LOL i can't control :)